# MacPort - jslint fails to install due to incompatible spidermonkey installation

Tags: macos, install, macports

*Problem Description in Brief:*
I am trying to install **jslint** which depends on the **spidermonkey** macport.  Installation of **spidermonkey** is successful, however, it appears to be incompatible with the installation of **jslint**.  Consequently, **jslint** is not installed.

*Problem Description in Detail:*
When I tried to install **jslint**, it successfully installed its dependency, **spidermonkey**, however, failed to install **jslint**.  Below is the error message that was returned, which I copied and pasted from the log that was produced.

```
:debug:configure configure phase started at Mon Nov 11 13:31:53 EST 2013
:notice:configure --->  Configuring jslint
:debug:configure Using compiler 'Xcode Clang'
:debug:configure Executing org.macports.configure (jslint)
:error:configure You need to install spidermonkey with the +fileobject variant in order to use jslint.
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port jslint returned: incompatible spidermonkey installation
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: incompatible spidermonkey installation
    while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for jslint: org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port jslint for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_jslint/jslint/main.log
```

This is a problem that has been reported to the MacPorts project, however, closed due to it being 'invalid'.  See the following link.

http://trac.macports.org/ticket/37053

So, my question is, how do I go about installing **spidermonkey** with the **+fileobject** variant in order to install and use **jslint**?  Furthermore, is there a way to configure macports so I don't have to do this each time I try to upgrade my macports?

Any advice/suggestions on how to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have spidermonkey installed, use `sudo port install jslint +fileobject`. If you already have it installed, you need to rebuild it with the `+fileobject` variant: `sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants spidermonkey +fileobject` and re-try installing jslint.

Comment: Thanks for that! It did the trick!  Was able to upgrade spidermonkey by enforcing its variants and, by doing so, was able to successfully install jslint.  Once again, thank you!!!!